# Wordpress not showing jQuery

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to link a new JavaScript file where I want to add some custom jQuery to the content. But it is not showing on my website or pages.

Here is the code in `functions.php` and my JavaScript file

```
function my_child_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-child',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-custom.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'my_child_script' );
```

and this is what am trying to do in my custom js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".block-title-wrap").hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi, Vijay, welcome to WPSE. The code looks incomplete, could you please edit and revise your post?

Comment: There is no such action like `wp_enqueue_script`. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead.

Comment: @MaxYudin you should post your solution as a solution not a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your add action line to this one: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_script' );` and check again

Comment: Thank you so much @Max Yudin , it was a silly typo mistake of the hook. Thank you all, I just added wp_enqueue_scripts instead of wp_enqueue_script